# Connecting Intel X722 SFP+ to Mellanox SX1012 QSFP via 4-split breakout cable using ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, networking, intel, sfp, mellanox

I have two servers running Ubuntu 18.04, each equipped with two SFP+ interfaces, each showing up in `lshw` like the following.

```
  *-network:1
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Ethernet Connection X722 for 10GbE SFP+
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0.1
       bus info: pci@0000:0a:00.1
       logical name: eno2
       version: 09
       serial: 7c:d3:0a:5e:e0:41
       capacity: 10Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi msix pciexpress vpd bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical 10000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=i40e driverversion=2.7.29 firmware=4.00 0x8000183c 1.1937.0 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes
       resources: iomemory:39f0-39ef iomemory:39f0-39ef irq:57 memory:39ffc000000-39ffcffffff memory:39ffe800000-39ffe807fff memory:d9d00000-d9d7ffff memory:39ffe000000-39ffe3fffff memory:39ffe810000-39ffe88ffff
```

The interfaces are also recognized and offer an mtu of 1500 bytes.

```
eno1: flags=4098<BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 7c:d3:0a:5e:e0:40  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

I installed the latest `i40e` driver from [Intel](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/24411/Network-Adapter-Driver-for-PCI-E-40-Gigabit-Network-Connections-under-Linux-). Connecting both servers directly with an SFP+ cable results in a link. Connecting them via a 4x10G SFP+ to QSFP to our Mellanox SX1012, however, does not. Neither side acknowledges any connection.

The switch's port with the breakout cable has been mapped as described [on Mellanox's website](https://community.mellanox.com/s/article/mellanox-breakout-cables-40g--gt--4x10g-and-100g--gt--4x25g). It is also configured with an MTU of 1500.

How can I connect these Intel interfaces with the Mellanox switch? I've read that it can be a bit iffy to connect Intel hardware to non-Intel hardware and I haven't worked with 10G ethernet before. If I'm missing something obvious, please tell me as well.

To make things easier, I also tried directly connecting the SFP+ from a server to the switch's QFSP with an appropriate cable, but to no avail. No link was established.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make that config work, but only using the optical sfp+ to sfp+ cable and a QSA to convert the switch end of the cable to QSFP